# How to check current postgres parallel configuratiions?

Tags: postgresql, parallel-processing

I did not enable parallel configurations in postgres.
However while debugging found that parallel configurations has been enabled.
On googling found how to set parallel configurations.
[Postgresql 10 - Parallel configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53059944/postgresql-10-parallel-configuration)

But how can I know my current configurations?

Postgres version: `PostgreSQL 10.6`

Comment: some details can be found here https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/229465/144614

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the settings e.g. using this:

```
select *
from pg_settings
where name like '%parallel%';
```

Or for individual settings, use e.g. `show max_parallel_workers_per_gather;`